# Python: If String with Dynamic Variables

Tags: python

Ok, This might be the wrong wording and I would love some one to correct me if so. I am trying to find out if a string contains a certain phrase, even if parts of that phrase us dynamic.

So for example, the string could be:

- Hi there, Jordan has enrolled at St. Thomas on 10/02/19
- Hi there, Lisa has enrolled at St. Thomas on 16/11/19
- Hi there, Craig has enrolled at Sirius Academy on 12/10/19

In my python I have this:

```
    if "Hi there, {$0} has enrolled at {$1} on ${2}" in email_body:
           print("Someone new is arriving...")
```

However it does not fire. If I print email_body it shows me the email so the problem is with the if statement and the regex detection.

## Weird Result Edit:

This is my code:

```
data = re.findall('Hi there, (.*?) has enrolled at (.*?) on (.*?)', message_body)[0]
print(data)
```

returns:

> ('Lisa', 'St. Thomas', '')

For some reason the third value is missing.

when i print(email_body) I am getting:

> Hi there, Lisa has enrolled at St. Thomas on 16thSept2017

Comment: What do you mean "problem with the regex detection"? There's no regular expression in your question

Answer (score 3):

You can use `re.findall`:

```
import re
email_body = 'Hi there, Lisa has enrolled at St. Thomas on 16/11/19'
if re.findall('Hi there, [\w\W]+ has enrolled at [\w\W]+ on [\w\W]+', email_body):
    print("Someone new is arriving...")
```

Regarding your recent comment, if you would like the entire line, you can just do this:

```
email_body = 'Hi there, Lisa has enrolled at St. Thomas on 16/11/19'
data = re.findall('Hi there, [\w\W]+ has enrolled at [\w\W]+ on [\w\W]+', email_body)
if data:
    print(data[0])
```

Output:

```
'Hi there, Lisa has enrolled at St. Thomas on 16/11/19'
```

**New Edit: More complex string**

```
email_body1 = '53ewwffHi there, Lisa has enrolled at St. Thomas on 16/11/19\n \n dfdsg 45435'
email_body2 = "Hi there, Lisa has enrolled at St. Thomas on 16thSept2017"
data = re.findall('Hi there, (.*?) has enrolled at (.*?) on ([a-zA-Z0-9/]+)', email_body1)
data1 = re.findall('Hi there, (.*?) has enrolled at (.*?) on ([a-zA-Z0-9/]+)', email_body2)
print(data[0])
print(data1[0])
```

Output:

```
('Lisa', 'St. Thomas', '16/11/19')

('Lisa', 'St. Thomas', '16thSept2017')
```

Comment: Is there a wildcard option for all those, what is some usernames gave zeros in, or are all special chars etc...  ?

Comment: ok, thanks, and one last question if you do not mind. How do I then print out those values? (You will get the points btw when SO lets me. Need to wait some time)

Comment: I get the error `IndexError: list index out of range`

Comment: @JamesG that is because you passed `re.findall` a string that did not yield a match.

Comment: @JamesG I made several changes in the code to help prevent that. Please see my recent edit.

Comment: @ajaz1234 Firstly thank you for all the help you are giving me. I really appreciate it. I have one final question: The reason I am getting that error I believe is because the string that is checked has weird issues, like extra \n or spaces etc... How do I check if that phrase is anywhere within email_body and then get those values? so, email body could be `53ewwffHi there, Lisa has enrolled at St. Thomas on 16/11/19\n \n  dfdsg 45435` and it would still work

Comment: @JamesG Glad to help! Please see my recent edit. I changed the regex so that it now matches a string with more special characters, but still retains the same general structure as before.

Comment: I am still not getting this to work, it got it to work 90% but for some reason I am getting Weird Results. Please see my Weird Result Edit on original post.

Comment: @JamesG I tweaked the code block under "New Edit: More complex string"  and it gets the correct results. Let me know what you think.

Answer (score 1):

You're correct that you'll want to use regular expressions here.  For example:

```
>>> import re
>>> r = re.match(r'Hi there, (.+) has enrolled at (.+) on (.+)', 'Hi there, Jordan has enrolled at St. Thomas on 10/02/19')
>>> r.groups()
('Jordan', 'St. Thomas', '10/02/19')
```

To use them:

```
>>> person, place, day = r.groups()
>>> '{} / {} / {}'.format(person, place, day)
'Jordan / St. Thomas / 10/02/19'
```

Comment: how would I get those values to print after? print($1) ?

Comment: @JamesG You can assign the tuple to variables then use the variables in your format call.  I updated my answer with an example.